# SharePoint 2013 Online - Is it possible to freeze panes for a task list (header row)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, task-list, datasheet

We have a task list containing many items.  The idea is to update the list in datasheet view. but Users complain that they **can't freeze the top header** row.

I have suggested filtering the content etc, but this does not satisfy their requirements.

I was thinking to use MSProject as an option. but unfortunately, we have a limited number of licenses for Project, so it has to be either SharePoint or Excel.

The ability for multiple synchronous editing and Outlook sync of the SharePoint task app outweighs Excel in some camps, but a louder group prefer the usability of Excel.

If I could freeze the header in datasheet view, I would be close to meeting both of their requirements.

I've seen some posts on how to do this for SP2010, but yet to see anything for SP2013 Online, and somewhere saw a note that this isn't feasible in the Online version.

Comment: http://spoodoo.com/sticky-headers-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I found this very useful script which does the trick: http://spoodoo.com/products/stickyheaders-for-sharepoint/